# Background Worker in windows form application C# does not block UI

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using background worker in my win form application I am showing progress bar form for a long running process and that long running process is on background worker.

**Note:** I have used background worker for showing progress bar in marquee style.

Problem I am facing is due to background worker my User interface gets responsive, but I don't want it to be responsive.

My code is as below:

```
ProgressBarForm progForm = new ProgressBarForm();
progForm.Show();
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork+= myMethod;
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: Then do it on the UI thread instead of a background worker? But why you want your UI to get unresponsive, exactly? Your progress bar won't fill up.

Comment: Why are you using background worker, if you want your UI to be unresponsive? This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: What did I just read...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering that you are using a form to display the progress, you can use `ShowDialog` instead of `Show`. This will open the window as a modal dialog, blocking UI actions to your underlying window until the progress window is closed.

Some things to consider:

- `ShowDialog` is a blocking call, so call it after starting the background worker.
- Make sure the user can't close the window, and programmatically close the window yourself after the background worker completes.

Comment: thanks Bas Brekelmans i tried your suggestion and got the result i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your user interface to be used, set .Enabled = false; on each of the form controls, then reverse the changes in _RunWorkerCompleted.

Just remember to leave any cancel / close buttons enabled :)